# Get the price of purchase at the moment of the sale

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the price of purchase at the moment of the sale. There are differents prices of purchase for the same product in my table.

The price of purchase is defined by two dates. One date for the start of the validity and one other for the end of validity : DATE_DEB_VALID and DATE_FIN_VALID.

If I want to know how many I won at the time of sale (FLIGHT_DATE), I have to know the purchase price to the same period.
My flight date must be between "DATE_DEB_VALID" and "DATE_FIN_VALID"

The two tables :

```
TB_DW_VAB_SALES     

 - ID_TEC_SALES 
 - TRANSACTION_NUMBER 
 - CARRIER_CODE 
 - MASTER_FLIGHT_NUMBER
 - FLIGHT_NUMBER 
 - FLIGHT_DATE
 - FLIGHT_CITY_DEP 
 - FLIGHT_CITY_ARR
 - PRODUCT_CODE 
 - QUANTITY
 - UNIT_SALES_PRICE
 - PROMOTION_CODE
 - CREW_PRICE 
 - COMPLEMENTARY 
 - SALES_TYPE 
 - DATE_CHGT

TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE 

     - PRODUCT_CODE  
     - PRODUCT_CODE_GUEST 
     - LIB_PRODUCT 
     - PRICE DATE_DEB_VALID
     - DATE_FIN_VALID 
     - DATE_CHGT
```

My request :

```
SELECT (TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE.PRODUCT_CODE),PRICE 
       FROM TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE,TB_DW_VAB_SALES 
       WHERE FLIGHT_DATE BETWEEN DATE_DEB_VALID AND DATE_FIN_VALID AND to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2016' OR to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015'
       GROUP BY TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE.PRODUCT_CODE, PRICE
```

Here We have the whole request (for informations) :

```
SELECT  to_char(DATE_VENTE,'MM/YYYY'),sum(MARGE_TOTALE) FROM (
    SELECT 
          CTE1.CA AS CHIFFRE_AFFAIRE_TOTAL,
          CTE2.PRICE AS COUT_UNITAIRE,
          CTE1.FLIGHT_DATE as DATE_VENTE,
          CTE1.QTE*CTE2.PRICE AS COUT_ACHAT,
          (CTE1.CA-CTE1.QTE*CTE2.PRICE) AS MARGE,
          sum((CTE1.CA-CTE1.QTE*CTE2.PRICE)) as MARGE_TOTALE
    FROM (
        SELECT PRODUCT_CODE,
         sum(QUANTITY*UNIT_SALES_PRICE) AS CA,
         FLIGHT_DATE,
         sum(QUANTITY) as QTE
        FROM TB_DW_VAB_SALES
        where SALES_TYPE = 'SALES' and to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015' OR  to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2016'
        group by to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'MM'),FLIGHT_DATE,PRODUCT_CODE
        ORDER BY to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'MM') ASC
      )CTE1

 inner join 
    (
       SELECT (TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE.PRODUCT_CODE),PRICE 
       FROM TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE,TB_DW_VAB_SALES 
       WHERE FLIGHT_DATE BETWEEN DATE_DEB_VALID AND DATE_FIN_VALID AND to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2016' OR to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015'
       GROUP BY TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE.PRODUCT_CODE, PRICE
    ) CTE2 
on CTE1.PRODUCT_CODE=CTE2.PRODUCT_CODE 
group by to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'MM'), FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM', CTE1.FLIGHT_DATE, (CTE1.CA-CTE1.QTE*CTE2.PRICE), 
CTE1.CA, CTE1.QTE, CTE2.PRICE, CTE1.QTE*CTE2.PRICE

) group by to_char(DATE_VENTE,'MM/YYYY') ORDER BY to_char(DATE_VENTE,'MM/YYYY') ASC;
```

Thank you !

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag.  The code is clearly Oracle.

Comment: The table structures (DDL), sample data and expected result would help. What exactly are you struggling with? DO you get an error, or just not the result you want?

Comment: No error, just an infinite loop

Comment: There is no loop - you mean it just doesn't complete in a reasonable time?  How big are the tables, what indexes do they have, and what does the execution plan show - you can add that to the question perhaps, Things like `to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015'` may be affecting you; `FLIGHT_DATE >= date '2015-01-01' and FLIGHT_DATE < date '2016-01-01'` would allow any index on that to be used, if it's appropriate for the data volumes. (Also, don't mix old and new style join syntax... stick to new!)

Comment: I mean Oracle has never gave me a result. Tables are very big, specially SALES. I tried without condition on the year, same thing happens

Comment: You need to start with the execution plan. We don't have the data or other vital info to diagnose your performance problem. But for a start you seem to have a cross join between sales and purchase in CTE2 (as Nemeros already pointed out). The whole query construction looks odd; really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nemeros already pointed out, you have a cross-join in your `CTE2` subquery, as you aren't linking sales and purchases together - other than by the flight/valid dates, but across all products, which can't be what you intended.

It looks like you're calculating things in your inline views (naming them CTE1/2 is slightly confusing as that usually refers to common table expressions or subquery factoring) which you then use for further calculations, but I don't think the intermediate steps or values are needed.

It (looks* like your query can be simplified to something like:

```
select to_char(trunc(s.flight_date, 'MM'),'MM/YYYY') as mois_du_sales,
  sum(s.quantity*(s.unit_sales_price - p.price)) as marge_totale
from tb_dw_vab_sales s
join tb_dw_vab_purchase p
on p.product_code = s.product_code
and s.flight_date between p.date_deb_valid and p.date_fin_valid
where s.sales_type = 'SALES'
and s.flight_date >= date '2015-01-01'
and s.flight_date < date '2017-01-01'
group by trunc(s.flight_date, 'MM')
order by trunc(s.flight_date, 'MM') asc;
```

Of course without sample data or expected results I can't verify I've interpreted it correctly. It may also not solve all of your performance problems - you still need to look at the tables and indexes and the execution plan to see what it's actually doing, and you might want to consider partitioning if you have a large volume of data and a convenient partition key (like sales year).

Using a filter like `to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015'` forces every value in that column (or at least those that match `sales_type`, if that is indexed and selective enough) to be converted to strings and then compared to the fixed value - twice as you're checking both years separately - and that stops any index on `flight_date` being used. Using a date range allows the index to be used, though unless you have data spanning many years it may still not be selective enough to be used, and the optimiser may still choose full table scans. But only one of each table, not two as you were potentially doing.

Comment: It works ! Thank you a lot !! 
Now I have now to optimize all my requests. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2):

I will just fix your initial query till you just forgotted your basic algebra (AND have more priority than OR) :

```
SELECT (TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE.PRODUCT_CODE),PRICE 
FROM TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE,TB_DW_VAB_SALES 
WHERE FLIGHT_DATE BETWEEN DATE_DEB_VALID AND DATE_FIN_VALID AND 
 (to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2016' OR to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015')
GROUP BY TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE.PRODUCT_CODE, PRICE
```

Now if you had used normalized join, you would have also seen that you had forgotten a join clause on the product_code, so finally :

```
SELECT PUR.PRODUCT_CODE, PRICE 
FROM TB_DW_VAB_PURCHASE PUR
inner join TB_DW_VAB_SALES SAL ON PUR.PRODUCT_CODE = PUR.PRODUCT_CODE 
  AND FLIGHT_DATE BETWEEN DATE_DEB_VALID AND DATE_FIN_VALID 
WHERE to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2016' OR to_char(FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')= '2015'
GROUP BY PUR.PRODUCT_CODE, PRICE
```

Comment: You need to provide the explain plan then if it's not working.